# How to send Soap request messages in Spring Ws to a Server which accepts Soap request messages?

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, soap, cxf

How do I configure my Spring MvC 4 Application with Spring WS to establish a two way SSL connection with a third party such as Bank .I need to exchange my certificates and also verify server certificates and then exchange Soap messages. If any links or code or procedure please kindly update

Comment: Do you want to produce a web service or consume one? I'm a bit confused...

It sounds like you want to consume one though.
Then you should have a look at this instead:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/

Comment: For clarification, where do you need the SSL connection? For the web service you want to consume?

Comment: I suggest you take some time to read the Spring WS reference guide... The guide tells you all that you need, apart from the SSL configuration.

Comment: @Steffen Harbich I need a Two way SSL connection to connect to a Bank Api to consume a service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your VM with the necessary properties for keystore and trustore as described [here in the JSSE doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#InstallationAndCustomization):

```
 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=yourKeystoreType(jks,pkcs12,etc.)
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=yourTruststoreType(jks,pkcs12,etc.)  
 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/your/keystore  
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/your/truststore
 -Djavax.net.debug=ssl  
 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=...  
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=...
```

Then in your client code you need to obtain the SSLSocketFactory

```
SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory =(SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
```

and attach it to the WebServiceTemplate (Snippet for creation of HttpClient taken from [ClientCustomSSL from apache examples](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomSSL.java)):

```
WebServiceMessageSender sender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender(HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsocketfactory ));
getWebServiceTemplate().setMessageSender(sender);
```

Comment: how do i use marshall and receive method after setting the MessageSender

Answer (score 4):

It is possible with Spring-WS. You have to use the `WebServiceTemplate` API provided by Spring WS. Following is the way to use it.

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.springframework.ws.WebServiceMessageFactory;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.WebServiceMessageSender;

public class WebServiceClient {

    private static final String MESSAGE =
        "<message xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org\">Hello Web Service World</message>";

    private final WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();

    public void setDefaultUri(String defaultUri) {
        webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(defaultUri);
    }

    // send to the configured default URI
    public void simpleSendAndReceive() {
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(MESSAGE));
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(source, result);
    }

    // send to an explicit URI
    public void customSendAndReceive() {
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(MESSAGE));
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult("http://localhost:8080/AnotherWebService",
            source, result);
    }

}
```

Please refer this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html)

And another useful [link2](https://blog.espenberntsen.net/tag/webservicetemplate/)